# Create a nested treeview like structure using the json response from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am create a Xamarin Forms cross platform application.

I am receiving a json response from a flask service. I want to be able to create a treeview like structure to display the nested "keys" in the json response and store the "values" in the json file as well.

The json file could have entries that are nested on many levels and i want to be able to make a generic solution.

I tried to use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FSTDInfo>(JsonContent);` but I have one issue as I am update the color of each "ItemName" by using the binding to the "BGColor". This "BGColor" is defined by the "taskstatus" field in each "keys" value field. For example, if the status is 1, then the color for the "Team" text will be red.

Thus I am not sure how to specify the binding in the xaml file.
I have done something like this but it will not work on the nested levels?

```
sfTreeView:SfTreeView x:Name="treeView"                             
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
            <sfTreeView:SfTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                                              RowSpacing="1"
                                              Padding="1,0,0,0"
                                              VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                               Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                                               BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sfTreeView:SfTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </sfTreeView:SfTreeView>
```

Currently, this is what I have.

```
 public async void GetJsonDataAsync(string uri)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string JsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FSTDInfo>(JsonContent);

                }
            }
```

My JSON structure is as following:

```
json_temp = {
        "TASKS":
         {            
                'taskid': '10',
                'taskstatus': 'in progress',

                'Kitchen': 
                {                    
                    'Stove':{
                                'LED1':
                                {
                                'taskid': '11',
                                'taskstatus':'running'
                                },

                                'LED2':
                                {
                                    'taskid': '12',
                                    'taskstatus':'off',
                                    'LEDSub':
                                    { 
                                       'taskid': '13',
                                       'taskstatus':'stable',
                                       'LEDSub2':
                                        {
                                           'taskid': '14',
                                           'taskstatus':'burnt'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                'LED3':
                                {
                                'taskid': '15',
                                'taskstatus':'new'
                                } 
                           },
                  //other nested layers
               }
        }
```

I know that I can create a c# class from a json structure but THAT IS SOMETHING I DONT WANT TO DO. I want to be able to create a treeview structure like this: So when we select Tasks, we get a drop down nested list based on the structure shown below.

```
>TASKS
  >Kitchen
    >Stove
      LED1
      LED2
      LED3
....
```

I am really lost on how to do this. I am using the SFtreeview in Xamarin Forms to create the tree view. I also tried to JSON parse method which could extract the keys in the json but it does not work.

I want to be able to create a treeview from a json object. I am not sure on how to do that. I want to create a class just for the "taskid" and "taskstatus" fields as they are same for all the keys and use binding to bind the 'background color of the each treeview node text(keys of the json) to their 'status' field.

I would appreciate any help. I am really lost.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to know how to create a binding for a color property?  Or are you asking more generally about how to build a treeview from a json object?  Why don't use want to create a C# class for your data?

Comment: @Jason I want to be able to create a treeview from a json object. I am not sure on how to do that. I want to create a class just for the "id" and "status" fields as they are same for all the keys and use binding to bind the 'background color of the each treeview node text(keys of the json) to their 'status'

Comment: @Jason I know that I have the json string stored in the JsonContent string. I want to be able to create the >TASKS
  >Kitchen
    >Stove
      LED1
      LED2
      LED3
....
``` by extracting the "keys" from the string and change the background color of each text by binding to their 'taskstatus'

Comment: @Jason I was wondering if you have any updates. :/

Comment: I don't know enough about the SFTreeView to say what kind of datasource it can work with.  You might be better off asking in the SF forums